# Headless UI's dropdown selected stops working after Inertia GET

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs, headless-ui

I'm using Headless UI as a part of the Tailwind UI's Vue implementation and Vue3 which work perfectly until Inertia is brought in.

The headless UI's `ListboxOption` has a `Selected` property which matches the Selected towards the model of the `Listbox` and returns a boolean.

This is my Dropdown's script:

```
export default {
    props: [
        'modelValue', 'label', 'options'
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            content: this.modelValue,
            selected: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {        
        handleInput (e) {
            this.content = e;
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.content)
        },
    },
    components: {
        Listbox,
        ListboxButton,
        ListboxLabel,
        ListboxOption,
        ListboxOptions,
        CheckIcon,
        SelectorIcon,
    },
    created() {
        this.selected = this.modelValue != '' ? this.modelValue : this.options[0];
    },
    watch: {
        selected(value) {
            this.handleInput(value)
        },
    }
}
```

If I don't do anything in the parent component when emiting update modelValue it all works perfectly. `Selected` is set properly etc.

When I do an Inertia.get with `preserveState` I can see that the `selected` property in the dropdown is updated and stays absolutely the same as when it works, but the `selected` property of the ListboxOption returns false.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to empty the selected array first then push the items into the selected array using the items that are tied to the array.

For example, if you have `nutrients` as the options and `selected_nutrients` as what is being v-modeled by the ListBox:

```js
const nutrients = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Calories' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Fat' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Cholesterol' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Sodium' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Carbohydrates' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Fiber' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Sugar' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Protein' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Vitamin A' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Vitamin C' },
    { id: 11, name: 'Calcium' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Iron' }
];

const selected_nutrients = ref([nutrients[0], nutrients[1], nutrients[4], nutrients[7]])
```

You would have to do something like this to get the ListBox to cooperate:

```js
selected_nutrients.value = [];
for (let i = 0; i < tracked_nutrition.length; i++) {
 selected_nutrients.value.push(nutrients[tracked_nutrition[i].id - 1]);
}
```